# IO.readlines to multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, string, file-io, dictionary

The goal of my program is to read in a file that has a grid of numbers delimited by white space. To process this in my program I need it to be a multidimensional array. I attempted to do this by:

```rb
arr = IO.readlines("Example.txt")  
arr.map { |string| string.chomp.split.map { |sub_str| sub_str.to_i } }
```

This code, when ran, will only return my original array, strings and '\n'. I have been able to get the desired effect by:

```rb
arr = IO.readlines("Example.txt")  
int = Array.new  
arr.each { |string| int << string.chomp.split.map { |sub_str| sub_str.to_i } }
```

I would prefer to mutate the original array rather that created a new one. How can I map the array to get the desired results? I am really new to Ruby and am enjoying its OOP'ness.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reassign the original array

```
arr = arr.map { |string| string.chomp.split.map { |sub_str| sub_str.to_i } }
```

Or use a destructive `map!`

```
arr.map! { |string| string.chomp.split.map { |sub_str| sub_str.to_i } }
```

Comment: Perfect! In the case of a non destructive #map, what is the difference between #each and #map?

Comment: @rafroehlich2: `#each` ignores value returned from the block. It's used to perform some action on each element, not to transform elements.